# SCPI Command VB.net negative integer to string error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, gpib

In VB.net, I am sending SCPI commands via GPIB-to-USB to an agilent/keysight device. I am using this sample to write data to instruments. https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=BR&lc=por&ckey=492255&nid=-33170.1090751.08&id=492255

Here is a portion of my code that I am having trouble with.

```
Dim P As Integer
    Dim Power As Integer
    For P = -50 To 0 Step 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Power = P
        instrument.WriteString("POW" & Str$(P) & "dbm")
        Console.WriteLine("Power" & P) 'Testing if this portion of the for loop is reached
```

My code builds successfully, but the device I am communicating with displays an error message saying "invalid separator." I believe the problem is that P starts as a negative number. If I were to do something like, For P=0 to 10 step 1, it would work on the device receiving the command. However, Str$ does not seem to be work with negative numbers. Using Console.WriteLine, I do see that my loop is working correctly in the console output. Based on the console output, the structure of the loop is not the problem.

How could I make this work with P starting as a negative number? I tested the code and device to see if it can take negative numbers by simply using instrument.WriteString("POW -5 dbm") and that works. I really believe the problem involves **Str$**. I also tried doing ("POW" & P.ToString() & "dbm") but that did not work either. I also replaced Str$ with CStr but that did not work either. Also note that the sleep/delay is not an issue because I implemented that in another for loop and it worked with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. There has to be a space after POW. It should look like "POW "